# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - C# Error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, object-reference

I know this gets asked a lot and I have read through similar posts but I can't figure my error out. I am getting the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error with a .aspx.cs file.

Here is a snippet of my code...the error is thrown by the `String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountInCrm.ParentAccountId.Id.ToString())` line.

Note: context is declared further up in my code and the enduserDropdown is a control I created using ASP.

```
foreach (var accountInCrm in context.AccountSet.ToList())
            {
                if (accountInCrm.StateCode == 0)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountInCrm.ParentAccountId.Id.ToString()))
                    {
                        enduserDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem(accountInCrm.Name, accountInCrm.Id.ToString()));
                    }
```

I know that accountInCrm is not empty and If I just remove the String.IsNullOrEmpty If statement all is well, and values are added to my dropdown.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

EDIT:------------------

```
foreach (var accountInCrm in context.AccountSet.ToList())
{
    if (accountInCrm.StateCode == 0)
    {
        if (accountInCrm.ParentAccountId != null)
        {
            enduserDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("test 2", accountInCrm.Id.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            enduserDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("test 3", accountInCrm.Id.ToString()));    
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:-------------retrieving data from CRM

```
var context = new XrmServiceContext();

foreach (var accountInCrm in context.AccountSet.ToList())
```

The loop goes through each account record in CRM. I know for sure that not all of the accounts in CRM have blank Parent Account Id's, some do but the majority don't.

Comment: Supposing that ID is just a string value then It seems that ParentAccountID is null

Comment: Just fyi that's probably most common exception in C#. When you get it there are some simple steps to solving it. First, find which line causes the error, next look for property access/method invocation on any references nearby, if any of your references are not checked for nullity prior to the access or method invocation then that line could throw a NullReferenceException (what you're getting). I think SO should host a guide on resolving NullReferenceExceptions, just a random thought as this comment isn't answer material but is more valuable than an actual solution.

Comment: The problem probably lies in the way you're retrieving the data from CRM. So you should probably show us the code that does that.

Comment: Updated my original post to include the context line I am using.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ParentAccountId` is probably null:

```
if (accountInCrm.ParentAccountId != null && 
     String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountInCrm.ParentAccountId.Id.ToString()))
                {
                    ...
                }
```

Comment: I've edited my above post with what I am trying now using the != null and all I am getting is "test 3" in my drop down...which means that all ParentAccountId's are null, but this is simply not true looking into CRM. Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ParentAccountID` could be null and thus you need to check for it.

```
if (accountInCrm.ParentAccountId != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountInCrm.ParentAccountId.Id))
{
    ...
}
```

Also keep in mind that you should not try to convert `ID` to a string.
If `ID` is already a string then there is no point in doing a ToString on it and, if it is null, calling ToString on a null reference will crash again your code.
If `ID` is not a string then you should probably not call `String.IsNullOrEmpty` on a non string object.

Comment: I've edited my above post with what I am trying now using the != null and all I am getting is "test 3" in my drop down...which means that all ParentAccountId's are null, but this is simply not true looking into CRM. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Are you sure that the database at which you are looking at is the same on which your code works? I mean, sometimes one looks at the database using Server Manager that use a different connection than the one used by the program.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing your Linq To CRM all wrong by doing all of your filtering on the client side.  You also want to only select the values that you actually need:

```
foreach(var account in AccountSet.Where (a => a.StateCode.Value == 0 && a.ParentAccountId != null).
                                  Select(a => new Account { Name = a.Name, AccountId = a.AccountId})
{
    enduserDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem(accountInCrm.Name, accountInCrm.Id.ToString()));
}
```

As long as enduserDropdown is not null that shouldn't be an issue.